# iphone-non-global uiimageview detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

Background:I am using XCode 3.1.4, keep this in mind. Please do not comment about it however.

I have to butttons, fire and start. When fire is pressed, a UIImageView named one is created using the IBAction function. When start is pressed, a UIImageview named two is created. Then, when *one is created in the IBACtion function, I call another function using an NSTimer that passes *one as a userinfo paramater. Then I have a move function which moves *one by 20 pixels down the y axis. This works perfectly and I can create hundreds of UIImageViews that move simultaneously. I do the same thing with start, but with a different UIImage and *two as the userinfo paramater. That also works perfectly. However, I want to make a collision detector for the UIImageViews created from clicking these buttons. Since the pointers assigned to these buttons are not global, I dont know how to do this. I am posting my code below:

```
-(IBAction)startWaves:(id)sender {
        start.hidden=YES;
    fire.hidden=NO;
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self   selector:@selector(createMeteors) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}


-(void)createMeteors{

    UIImageView *one = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Meteor.png"]];
    CGRect rectOne = CGRectMake(arc4random() % (310), arc4random() % (1), 35, 35);
    [one setFrame:rectOne];
    [self.view addSubview:one];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.4 target:self selector:@selector(moveMeteorOne:) userInfo:one repeats:YES];





}

- (void)moveMeteorOne:(NSTimer *)timerOne {
    UIImageView *one = timerOne.userInfo;
    one.center=CGPointMake(one.center.x, one.center.y + 15); 
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(one.frame, image.frame)) {
        background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gameOver.png"]; 
        fire.hidden = YES; 
        image.hidden=YES; 

    }
}


-(void)createBullets{
    UIImageView *two = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lazerBeam.png"]];
    CGRect rectTwo = CGRectMake((image.center.x), (image.center.y - 45), 7, 20);
    [two setFrame:rectTwo];
    [self.view addSubview:two];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveBulletOne:) userInfo:two repeats:YES];

}

-(void)moveBulletOne:(NSTimer *)timerTwo {
    UIImageView *two = timerTwo.userInfo;
        two.center=CGPointMake(two.center.x, two.center.y - 15); 

}

-(IBAction)fireBullets:(id)sender {

    [self createBullets]; 

}
```

Comment: Xcode version is irrelevant, you could mention SDK and compiler version instead. As for collisions detection, you can store the same imageviews' references somewhere, for example at arrays or sets.

Comment: Can I have an example of how would I implement this in code?

Comment: Create two instances of `NSMutableArray` somewhere, add the objects created at `createMeteors` and `createBullets` to related arrays (let's say they are called `meteorsArray` and `bulletsArray`). Then for a collision detection you can iterate through the `meteorsArray` and look for collision with each object from `bulletsArray` or vise versa. Try to do it and update your question with a new code if you have any problem.